# Ruby: get a reference in a method context to the object that self is an attribute of

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have a setup like this:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar

  def initialize
    @bar = Bar.new
  end
end

class Bar
  def bar_method
    self.class # => Bar
    whatever???.class # => Foo
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.bar.bar_method
```

I know that I can set up the method like this:

```
def bar_method(selfs_self)
  selfs_self.class # => Foo
end
```

And call the method like this: `foo.bar.bar_method(foo)` to get what I want. But that seems pretty redundant. Is there any way, inside of `bar_method`, that I can get a reference to `foo`, without specifically passing in a reference to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Usually this is done by passing a reference to the parent object when initializing child objects, like:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar

  def initialize
    @bar = Bar.new(self)
  end
end

class Bar
  attr_reader :foo

  def initialize(foo)
    @foo = foo
  end

  def bar_method
    self.class # => Bar
    foo.class # => Foo
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect. That's what I was looking for. Passing the reference through to the method was just messy, and I was running down a blind alley trying to clean it up. Of course this is the way to do it. Thank you!